# Регулярное выражение для удаления тега input

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Пытаюсь сделать замену текста по регулярке, как не пробовал составлять регулярку, в результате либо вообще ничего не заменяет (то есть текст остается без изменений), либо вся переменная в которой хранятся текст обнуляется... Почему не знаю...

Делаю так:

```
$content=preg_replace('/<input name="channels[]" value="(.*?)"
type="checkbox">/is','',$text);
```

Comment: А что надо-то в итоге получить?

Comment: есть переменная $text в которой часть кода с распрасеной страницы, в ней есть вот такие конструкции 
<input name="channels[]" value="16588" type="checkbox"><a href="16588.html">TV-5</a><br>
<input name="channels[]" value="17142" type="checkbox"><a href="17142.html">Детский канал</a>

мне нужно удалить все выводы input, и оставить только ссылки... можно конечно распарсить отдельно ссылки и текст ссылки и вывести в нужном формате... но в переменной есть еще много кода который нужно сохранить... вобщем нужно почистить от input

Comment: @arashvg, как минимум ``channels\[\]``

Comment: channels\\[\\] оставляет код без изменений...

Comment: И <input вместо <input>. Ответ только [один](http://bit.ly/HNkn7h)

Comment: у меня в крипт так и написано  <input  просто в вопросе незнаю откуда появилась лишня скобка...

Comment: $s = '<input name="channels[]" value="16588" type="checkbox"><a href="16588.html">TV-5</a><br> <input name="channels[]" value="17142" type="checkbox"><a href="17142.html">Детский канал</a>';
    $c=preg_replace('/<input name\="channels\[\]" value\=".*?" type\="checkbox">/is','',$s);
    print "$c\n";

Вывод:

    <a href="16588.html">TV-5</a><br> <a href="17142.html">Детский канал</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалит все теги input без исключения

```
$text = preg_replace('|<input.*>|Ui', '', $text);
```

Или только точное совпадение

```
$text = preg_replace('|<input name="channels\[\]" value="[0-9]+" type="checkbox">|Ui', '', $text);
```

Comment: спасибо, я что-то не подумал что можно проще сделать )))

Comment: Проверьте первое выражение на тексте:  

    <input random /><div></div>

Comment: @ReinRaus А про модификатор `U` вы не слышали? Или я ваш намек неправильно понял? ;)

Comment: Первое выражение удалит в тексте все от первого вхождения `<input` до последнего вхождения `>`. В тексте, который я привел это весь текст полностью.  
Исправляется так:  

    <input .*?> или
    <input[^>]*>
Второй вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: @ReinRaus Да, про `U` то вы явно не в курсе, а эта волшебная буковка, убирает "прожорливость" регулярки, поэтому удалено будет до первого вхождения `>`

Comment: Да, верно. Спутал с unicode. Поэтому лучше минимальный квантификатор использовать- выражение станет универсальным и для тех языков, где нет модификатора такого.  
Извините за ошибочное замечание. Ушел учить матчасть :)